# Cycle jQuery, How to stop the slide show after second loop?

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

Hello friends i am working on jQuery cycle plugin its cool but i am stuck when my client want its to stop after 2nd loop then i go to google to find out the way then i find `nowrap : 1` method but its not help me to stop slide show after 2nd loop its stop my loop after 1 loop please help me following id my code.

**Script**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $('#slider_home').cycle({
            fx:'fade',
         speed:400,
        timeout:3000,
        nowrap:  2,
        cleartypeNoBg:true,
        pager:'#nav_slider',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function paginate(idx, el) {
            return '<li><a class="service' + idx + '" href="#" >&bull;</a></li>';
}
})
});
</script>
```

Please help me

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use `after` option to count cycles and when you are in the 2nd iteration of the loop, do :

```
$('#slider_home').cycle('stop');
```